# MY SQL help - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, terminal

I am trying to copy an SQL database from the folder using this command:

sudo mysql -u root globe_bank 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
sudo mysql -u root -p globe_bank 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I rang apple support and we changed the password of the root directory, they confirmed it was successful still getting this message. I have tried a few of the suggestions on similar threads, and mostly I get command not found.

When I type in mysql my connection ID is 19.

Any ideas or help is appreciated

Comment: I'm a little confused: why would Apple support know the root password? Are you sure you have the right password? You mentioned that you tried a few other things: what were they?

Comment: Just try with `mysql -u root` and see if you can get into. Make sure you are logged in from root user. You can use `sudo -i` to switch to root user

Comment: mysql -u root command not found :(

Comment: Apple help me reset the root password they didnt know it.

Comment: If you are getting command not found, you are definitely not the `root`. It seems you are only able to access mysql from root user. Make sure you are `root` user first.

Comment: http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/04/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-user-host-using-password-YES.html
Check this link

Comment: Thank you for sending that rathish! I will take a look at it and let you know how I go.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on mysql Ver 15.1 on Amazon Linux 2 and the following worked for me:

Try entering the password on the same line.

I.e. instead of `$mysql -u root -p`, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then entering password after the prompt, do this:

```
$mysql -u root -p\<password>
```

Remember there is no "space" between `-p` and `\<password>`, I think you have got a space there!